# Kernel data segment variables address translation (virt to physical)

Tags: linux-kernel, virtual-memory

So I saw the `virt_to_phy` function in `asm/io.h` but this only works for kmalloc allocated memory, is there an equivalent for memory allocated in the data segment? For example, global variables (which includes a page table walk right?).

Answer (score 0):

Such a function would make no sense. In fact, it only makes sense in a kernel that does not page, as in Linux.

In the user space, the mapping changes. By the time you got a return value from such a function, the mapping could already be changed.

Comment: I disagree, for example I have an IO port (VMware) which requires a PA to which it will write some data.

Comment: I would love it if you can elaborate...
That is my current situation (Working with a VMware IO port API that requires a PA to write the data to, meaning I make an IO operation to some port with a PA in 2 registers, and in response the data I asked for is written to that PA).
Are suggesting that even global variable that I define in the kernel can be translated to PA by reducing the base address (same as variables that were allocated using kmalloc)?
If not, please elaborate, would to learn something new :)
PA = Physical Address

Comment: There are no physical addresses in the user space.

Comment: @user3344003 Might not have been completely clear from my comment but its all in kernel space